# Does IronPython and Jython have the same GIL issues as CPython?

Tags: python, ironpython, jython

I read about the problems with CPython and CPU bound threads and the GIL and some changes in Python 3.2.

Do IronPython and Jython have this same problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, neither have a GIL at all.

See [previous answer about Jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120354/does-jython-have-the-gil) and I[ronPython wiki page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/IronPython).

Comment: To stay fast (and safer) in other Python interpreters, use [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).